# If $\|u\|^2 = c^2$, then $\|\dot x\|^2 \to a $ for $\ddot x = -\dot x + u(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces, control-theory

I am dealing with the next simple equation

$$
\ddot x = -\dot x + u(t),
$$
where $u, x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, with $m \geq 1$, and I am wondering if for $\|u\|^2 = c^2 > 0$ then $\|\dot x\|^2\to a$, where $a\in\mathbb R^+$.

For the trivial case of having $m = 1$ it is clear, however I do not know whether is true for $m > 1$. Any hints or references?

**Edit**

The next computations show me a bound for $||\dot x(t)||$, but I do not know how to show that it converges to a constant (if this is indeed the case).

Take $y = \dot x$, then

$$
y(t) = e^{-t}y(0)+\int_0^\tau e^{-I(t-\tau)}u(\tau)d\tau \\
|y(t)| \leq e^{-t}|y(0)|+\int_0^\tau \left|e^{-I(t-\tau)}\right| \, \left|u(\tau)\right|d\tau \\
|y(t)| \leq e^{-t}|y(0)|+ \sup (|u(\sigma)|)_{0\leq\sigma\leq\tau} \int_0^\tau \left|e^{-I(t-\tau)}\right| d\tau,
$$
and knowing that $|u(t)| = c, \forall t$, then

$$
|y(t)| \leq e^{-t}|y(0)| + c \\
$$
Then if I take the limit $t\to\infty$ in the before expression. I can conclude that $|y(t)| \leq c$, so $|\dot x(t)| \leq c$ when $t\to\infty$.

How to continue from here? I suspect that it is related with energy. If we are pumping constant energy and the system can only disipate certain energy per unit of time, they will reach an equilibrium in the sense of energy, i.e. $\dot x(t)$ might not be constant but its norm yes.

Comment: what is the definition of $a$?

Comment: sorry, I will edit the question. $a$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u$ represents an external force that is periodic, we can expect that forced oscillation occurs. In other words, we expect an asymptotically periodic solution of $\dot{x}(t)$ in this case. So there are plenty of rooms to create asymptotic periodicity of $|\dot{x}(t)|$ as well.

Indeed, consider $m = 2$ and identify $(\Bbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|) \simeq (\Bbb{C}, |\cdot|)$. Let $k > 0$ and consider

$$ u(t) = \exp(ik\sin t). $$

Then we have

\begin{align*}
\dot{x}(t)
&= e^{-t}\dot{x}(0) + \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\tau}u(t-\tau) \, d\tau \\
&= e^{-t}\dot{x}(0) + \int_{0}^{t} \exp(-\tau + ik\sin(t-\tau)) \, d\tau \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\tau + ik\sin(t-\tau)) \, d\tau + \mathcal{O}(e^{-t}).
\end{align*}

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb{C}$ be defined by

$$f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\tau + ik\sin(t-\tau)) \, d\tau. $$

Then $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic. So it suffices to find two values $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $|f(t_1)| \neq |f(t_2)|$. This can be achieved by taking some appropriate choices of $t_1$, $t_2$ and performing numerical integration.

The trajectory of $f(t)$ for $k = 6$ is given below:

[image]

Comment: You answer is really useful for me since in my problem I want to explain such behavior later on. But you are addressing a more general problem with general periodic $u(t)$. In particular I am interested only in the next kind of inputs $|u(t)| = a$. Can we say something else more under such constraint? If $u(t)^Tu(t) = a$, then your $f(t)^Tf(t)$ converges to a constant right? Can we extrapolate that to $m=3$ without using complex numbers?

Comment: @noether, I think I am not understanding your constraint. My example satisfies $|u(t)| = 1$ for any $t$. Isn't it all that you required?

Comment: oh, you are right, so sorry for the misunderstanding. Therefore $f(t)^Tf(t) \neq a, a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ when $t \to \infty$ right?

Comment: @noether, Exactly. And this example generailzed to higher dimensions in an obvious way: we can consider $$u(t) = (\cos(k\sin t), \sin(k\sin t), 0, \cdots, 0).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice explanation and your time. Now I have to look at my problem in a different way.

Comment: @noether, You're welcome! And I also believe that your guess is close to the truth, as many other examples I have tried seem to yield limit of $|\dot{x}(t)|$.

Comment: Is there any requirement for forcing a limit to $|\dot x(t)|$? I will start to look at it, any hints for starting with?

Comment: @sos440, but your method can be used for $u(t)$ which does not have the form you are using? $m>2$ is also a problem.

Comment: @xpaul, Periodicity of $f(t)$ defined so was a crucial key for the proof, which we barely expect for general $u(t)$. So I wonder which example you are thinking of. Also why do you think that $m > 2$ is a problem?

Comment: @noether, I have no idea, but I see a faint similarity between this and [*stationary phase approximation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation)...

Comment: @sos440, I mean that you use $u(t)=\exp(ik\sin t)$ in your answer. For general $u$ and $m>2$, it is not working.

Comment: @xpaul, as I mentioned in the comment above, this readily generalizes to higher dimensions by embedding $\Bbb{R}^2$ into $\Bbb{R}^n$ in an obvious way. Notice that the identification $\Bbb{R}^2 \simeq \Bbb{C}$ is just introduced to simplify notations and calculations, but it is able to write down everything using planar vectors. Hence it generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: @sos440, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: by the way, thanks for the link about stationary phase

Comment: @sos440. I have reduced my problem to consider only the input $u(t) = \exp{(i \omega t)}, \omega\in\mathbb{R}^+$. If I have such $u(t)$ then $|f(t)|$ will be constant, am I correct?

Comment: I have done the computations and indeed, with this particular $u(t)$ we can find an analytic expression for $x(t)$ which is periodic with the same frequency $\omega$. In the end this is why I have expected since the system is linear and we have "excited" it with an ouput generated by another linear system.

Comment: @noether, I also think that $u(t) = \exp(i\omega t)$ will work, in view of the formula for the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is BIBO (Bounded Input Bounded Output) stability if you select $y = \dot{x}$. It is well-known that if a LTI system is asymptotically stable, then it is also BIBO stable. Since your system is clearly asymptotically stable ($A = -I$), your statement is true.

**Edit:** It is asymptotically stable for all $m$. The solution is

$$\dot{x}(t) = \int_0^t e^{-I(t - \tau)} u(\tau) d \tau$$

for $x(0) = 0$. Since $u$ is bounded and $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-It} = 0$, this integration is finite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see clearly that the system is BIBO for $m=1$. However, how can I check it for $m>1$? how can I see that the norm of $\dot x$ converges to a constant?

Comment: @noether I've updated my answer. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Therefore $\dot x(t)^T \dot x(t) = c \int_0^t e^{-2I(t-\tau)} d\tau$ right? Then the norm converges to a constant. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @noether Well, actually it is more complex than that, which involves double integration. However the idea is the same. For a more rigorous proof, you need integral and norm inequalities.

Comment: I can prove that the solution is indeed bounded (BIBO). But I cannot see why the solution is asymptotically stable if $u(t)$ is not constant, only its norm.

Answer (score 0):

The important property of the system under study is that the transition matrix is given by $e^{At}=e^{-t}\mathbb{I}_n$. So the ODE solution is $\dot{x}(t)=e^{-t}\dot{x}(t_0)+\int_0^t{e^{-(t-s)}u(s)ds}$. By direct calculation we then have $\|\dot{x}(t)\|^2=x^T(t)x(t)=e^{-2t}\|\dot{x}(t_0)\|^2+2e^{-t}\int_0^t{e^{-(t-s)}u^T(s)ds}\dot{x}(t_0)+{\int_0^t\int_0^t{e^{-[2t-(s_1+s_2)]}u^T(s_1)u(s_2)ds_1ds_2}}.$

The first two terms converge exponentially to zero and therefore $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\bigg[\|\dot{x}(t)\|^2-{\int_0^t\int_0^t{e^{-[2t-(s_1+s_2)]}u^T(s_1)u(s_2)ds_1ds_2}}\bigg]=0 $

but I cannot see an obvious reason for $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}{\int_0^t\int_0^t{e^{-[2t-(s_1+s_2)]}u^T(s_1)u(s_2)ds_1ds_2}}=a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I also arrived to such expression. We know that $u(t)^Tu(t) = a, \forall t$. Do you think we can relate this somehow to $u^T(s_1)u(s_2)ds_1ds_2$? since we are integrating in the same range $[0, t]$.